# Sorting unique high values in file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a data file with following lines:

```
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b171_b174_b236_b242_qreg/d2    19.33    18.65    -0.67 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b186_b196_b210_b223_qreg/d2    15.09    11.70    -3.39 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b103_b104/d2    40.35    36.61    -3.74 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    11.06     8.77    -2.29 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    40.08    29.18   -10.90 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b119_b120/d2    11.37     8.34    -3.03 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    14.56     4.41   -10.15 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    45.82    27.47   -18.34 (VIOLATED)
```

And I need to get the unique value and the smallest one for the fourth column with corresponding 1st column.

Output should be:

```
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b171_b174_b236_b242_qreg/d2    19.33    18.65    -0.67 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b186_b196_b210_b223_qreg/d2    15.09    11.70    -3.39 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b103_b104/d2    40.35    36.61    -3.74 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    40.08    29.18   -10.90 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b119_b120/d2    11.37     8.34    -3.03 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    45.82    27.47   -18.34 (VIOLATED)
```

I tried using pattern matching to get the column 1 and column 4 in hash and then sort the hash. But its not working the way i want. Please help.

```
while(<FILE1>) {
    my $path = $_;
    $path =~ /([^\s]+)/;
    $path = $1; #Extracting path
    chop($path);
    my $slack = $_;
    #$slack =~ /([^\s+]+)[\d+][\s+][\d+][\s+]([^\f+]+)[\s](VIOLATED)/;
    $slack =~ /[^\f+][\s+][\f+][\s+][\f+][\s+]([\f+]+)[\s](VIOLATED)/;
    $slack = $1;
    print "$slack\n";
    chop($slack);
    print FILE2 "$slack\n";
}
```

Comment: What patterns have you tried?

Comment: while(<FILE1>){

        my $path = $_;
        $path =~ /([^\s]+)/;  
        $path = $1;        #Extracting path
        chop($path);
        
        my $slack = $_;
        
        #$slack =~ /([^\s+]+)[\d+][\s+][\d+][\s+]([^\f+]+)[\s]\(VIOLATED\)/;
        $slack =~ /[^\f+][\s+][\f+][\s+][\f+][\s+]([\f+]+)[\s]\(VIOLATED\)/;
        $slack = $1;
        print "$slack\n";
        chop($slack);
        
        
        print FILE2 "$slack\n";

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like (if the filenames don't contain spaces in them):

```
my %res;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @vals = split/\s+/;
    $res{$vals[0]} = {} unless exists $res{$vals[0]};
    if (!exists($res{$vals[0]}{value}) || $vals[3] < $res{$vals[0]}{value}) {
        $res{$vals[0]}{value} = $vals[3];
        $res{$vals[0]}{line} = $_;
    }
}
say $res{$_}{line} for keys %res;

__DATA__
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b171_b174_b236_b242_qreg/d2    19.33    18.65    -0.67 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b186_b196_b210_b223_qreg/d2    15.09    11.70    -3.39 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b103_b104/d2    40.35    36.61    -3.74 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    11.06     8.77    -2.29 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    40.08    29.18   -10.90 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b119_b120/d2    11.37     8.34    -3.03 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    14.56     4.41   -10.15 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    45.82    27.47   -18.34 (VIOLATED)
```

**output:**

```
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b186_b196_b210_b223_qreg/d2    15.09    11.70    -3.39 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b105_b106/d1    40.08    29.18   -10.90 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b103_b104/d2    40.35    36.61    -3.74 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b119_b120/d2    11.37     8.34    -3.03 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar11/dmunit1/mt_dm_fifo_csr_flopped_out/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_reg_0_b171_b174_b236_b242_qreg/d2    19.33    18.65    -0.67 (VIOLATED)
gtssmpar21/flunit1/flunitx1/fl_flex1/fl_mt_input_fifo/u_gt_ram/wrdataR_dreg_b11_b12/d2    45.82    27.47   -18.34 (VIOLATED)
```

Comment: @user1769932: If it works for you, feel free to accept the answer :-)

Comment: Hi, yes this method works for me. But I have tried this:my %data;
while ( <> ) {
    my ( $first, undef, undef, $fourth ) = split;
    if ( !exists $data{ $first } || $data{ $first }{ fourth } > $fourth) {
        $data{ $first } = { fourth => $fourth, line => $_ };
        }
    }

for my $key ( sort keys %data ) {
    print $data{ $key }{ line };
    }